# Container Error Deploying Streamlit App to Azure App Service when App Not Containerized

Tags: python, azure, streamlit

I am working on deploying a Streamlit app to an Azure Web App Service instance, yet I keep getting container errors when I have not containerized the app. I have tried deploying to a new instance, changing the service plans, different configurations and still get that same error. Is anyone familiar with this and able to help? I can't seem to find where any of the container settings are configured given I never containerized the app.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the code from this [document](https://docs.streamlit.io/get-started/tutorials/create-an-app) and successfully deployed it to the Azure App Service.

**app. py**:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
st.title('Uber pickups in NYC')
DATE_COLUMN = 'date/time'
DATA_URL = ('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/'
            'streamlit-demo-data/uber-raw-data-sep14.csv.gz')
@st.cache_data
def load_data(nrows):
    data = pd.read_csv(DATA_URL, nrows=nrows)
    lowercase = lambda x: str(x).lower()
    data.rename(lowercase, axis='columns', inplace=True)
    data[DATE_COLUMN] = pd.to_datetime(data[DATE_COLUMN])
    return data
data_load_state = st.text('Loading data...')
data = load_data(10000)
data_load_state.text("Done! (using st.cache_data)")
if st.checkbox('Show raw data'):
    st.subheader('Raw data')
    st.write(data)
st.subheader('Number of pickups by hour')
hist_values = np.histogram(data[DATE_COLUMN].dt.hour, bins=24, range=(0,24))[0]
st.bar_chart(hist_values)
hour_to_filter = st.slider('hour', 0, 23, 17)
filtered_data = data[data[DATE_COLUMN].dt.hour == hour_to_filter]
st.subheader('Map of all pickups at %s:00' % hour_to_filter)
st.map(filtered_data)
```

**requirements.txt**:

```json
streamlit1  ==  0.1.0
```

I enabled the virtual environment by running the commands below.

```
 python -m venv venv
 .\venv\Scripts\activate
```

I ran the command below to run the application.

`streamlit run app.py`

[image]

I deployed a Streamlit app to Azure App Service using VS Code as shown below.

[image]

After successfully deploying to the Azure Web app, I added this in the Startup command: Configuration -> General settings -> Startup Command ->

`python -m streamlit run <YourFileName>.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0`

in the Azure Web app as shown below.

This helps to start the Container.

[image]

**Azure App Service Output**:

[image]